# How to set menustrip icon from txt file C#

Tags: c#, menustrip

I have a txt file and this is the content :

```
Itemname|path/to/my/icon.png
```

I used this code:

```
foreach (var txt in readText)
{
     string i = txt.Split(new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
     ToolStripItem subItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(i);
     nToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(subItem);

}
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(@"Path\item.txt");
```

I have success in adding the item to the menustrip but how can I set the icon for those item.

```
string icon = txt.Split(new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
```

**I have came up with a solution:**

```
foreach (var txt in readText)
        {
            string i = txt.Split(new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
            ToolStripItem subItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(i);
            subItem.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(txt.Split(new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]);
            nToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(subItem);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Bitmap.FromFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536290(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
subItem.Image = Bitmap.FromFile("filepath");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(@"Path\item.txt");
foreach (string txt in readText)
{
    string i = txt.Split(new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];

    ToolStripItem subItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(i);
    var iconImage = new Bitmap(i[1].Replace("/", @"\"));
    subItem.Image = iconImage;

    nToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(subItem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks u but I have came up with a solution